# Abstract class calling a method from the wrong child class

Tags: php, class, abstract

I have an abstract class that is extended by several other classes, each with an abstract method called `child_save_changes()`.

One of the methods in the template class is called `on_save_changes()`, and whenever the user clicks 'Submit', this method is called from another page.

The `on_save_changes()` method first sets some class variables required for validating/saving, then calls `child_save_changes()`, and then finally handles redirection back to the referring page.

The problem is, because I'm calling `on_save_changes()` via a callback from another page, it doesn't know which child class to call the abstract method `child_save_changes()` from, and thus it's just picking the first one it finds.

It seems inefficient to repeat code in each `child_save_changes()` method, so I'm wondering if anyone has come across a similar scenario in the past, and what actions they took to fix the issue? Thanks.

Comment: What you are describing doesn't sound like a traditional implementation of OOP abstraction.  Abstract classes don't have children in the sense that it contains more than one inheriting instance of itself.

Comment: @Flosculus - I've added a basic example of what I'm doing to this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mnWbUetf). I believe my issues is that `on_save_changes()` is being called independently, not from within one of the child classes. Does this fit your expectation of OOP abstraction, or am I on the wrong path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are using static methods. Otherwise the problem you describe cannot reasonably occur.

You wrote, "`on_save_changes()` does not know which child class to call the abstract method `child_save_changes()` from". But ordinary (i.e., non-static) methods are not called from classes, they are called from objects. And every object knows exactly which class it belongs to, and thus there can never be confusion about which method is meant to be called.

Static methods, on the other hand, are not designed to work with inheritance hierarchies like that. I would personally recommend refactoring your code and turn them into non-static ones, but if you do not want to do that, you may be able to make it work using [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).